# How to change WCF binding of a third party component?

Tags: performance, wcf, wcf-binding

I have a third party application, built with WCF. It is installed as a windows service and it supports **`wsHttpBinding`** and **`basicHttpBinding`** by default.

Is there a way to switch to a more optimized binding such as **`tcpBinding`** or **`named pipes`**?

I will be consuming the service within same server so named pipes is an option.

I want to know if I can do it on a third party just by modifying the .config files of the windows service.

Answer (score 3):

If the WCF server service you mention is using  ".config" files to initialize, then it should be possible to modify the behavior (that's the whole point in using config files: you can modify parameters without the need to recompile the code).

Try to add a new binding configuration and modify the endpoint's "binding" and "bindingConfiguration" attributes to point the new one.

In the client configuration,set up the same binding type, or if you have metadataExchange configured, update the service references and see if the client's configuration is updated.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a new binding config in the app.config for the service with a contract attribute that matches the type you want to host differently. This creates a separate service host, which may or may not matter to the component/service. The contract attribute is key here, as that is how WCF will determine which binding/endpoint configuration to use. "WCF ABC = Address, Binding, Contract", specify those three and you should be up and running.

It's also possible to host a Windows Service WCF service as an IIS WCF service by referencing the necessary assemblies in, say, a web app project and then creating the necessary .svc file which identifies the appropriate base class.